# Show time cookie started

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I am trying to show the time a user logged in by using the time a cookie was set.

Set the cookies:

```
setcookie("loggood", "YES", $expire, "/", "", 0);  
setcookie("user", $pid, $expire, "/", "", 0);
```

Can anyone help?... is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could set another cookie or replace the value of **loggood** with the time of creating the user id cookie :

```
setcookie("loggedin",time(),$expire,"/");
```

Or :

```
setcookie("loggood",time(),$expire,"/");
```

Then echo as date format :

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$_COOKIE['loggedin']);
```

Comment: Or overload one of the other cookies, e.g. use the time() as the value for "loggood" rather than just the constant "YES".